# How to use multiple regex expressions for one string

Tags: regex, go

Is there any way to store both types of these "tags" by using Golang and regex.

Here is an example of said tags:

```
<tag1>hello
my name is Matt</tag1><tag2>goodbye!</tag2>
```

I have tried many approaches at this, however on each try it only manages to pick up "tag1".

Here is the regular expression I am using: `<(tag1|tag2)>((.|\n)*)</(tag1|tag2)>`.

Comment: I think  you want a non greedy quantifier `*?` but I would suggest looking into a parser instead of a regex.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I will have a look at a parser, thankyou for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The regex you're using will also incorrectly match text with mismatched tag openings and endings (e.g. `<tag1>Hello!</tag2>`). If you modify your regex like the following, both tags will be matched:

`(<tag1>((.|\n)*)</tag1>)|(<tag2>((.|\n)*)</tag2>)`

But as mentioned by someone else in the comments, using a parser is probably the better solution here. By the looks of it even an XML parser could help you with your use case and you don't need to write new grammar.